# Audio and Video Out of Sync when Streaming From Arch Linux MiniDLNA Server to Roku TV

Tags: dlna

Last week I switched over from Ubuntu 19.2 to Arch. On Ubuntu I was running a MiniDLNA server. I would use that to stream movies to my Roku TV. I don't ever recall having any problems with audio and video syncing up.

I attempted the same setup on Arch, however now I am finding that audio and video are not exactly synchronizing. This is odd to me because I am using the same files as I was using previously, and the audio and video seemed like they were synced up back then, and additionally when I try running those same files in VLC, the audio and video are synchronized.

My system should be fully up to date, and I am running Minidlna 1.3.0. Any ideas as to what I might be able to try to fix this?

Thanks!